# I got confused by learning the wrong Grammar terms. What are the real ones and where to learn them?

Tags: grammar, terminology

When I started to learn English, I did it with half a century old Soviet book called *The Practical English Grammar* by Izrailevich and Kachalova (Практическая грамматика английского языка. Израилевич и Качалова).

There are sections in the textbook about *the Syntax* and *the Morphology* of the language. As far as the Morphology section is concerned everything's looked spot on so far.
But I started learning the Syntax which explores not the parts of speech as units but a whole sentence. And there I began to see problems.

It's just that some terms in the book which break sentences into components don't seem to align with the ones people use around here, on this site. But, oddly enough, those terms try to be analogous to the Russian terms in the Syntax of the Russian language. So my point is that the textbook tries to make me learn the English Syntax through the Russian terms.

I've done some googling and found out that all the other Russian *English learning* resources offer those Russian-like terms too. But the real English speaking world seems to use a different taxonomy, as it were.

On this site I find terms such as *Prepositional Phrase*, *Complement*, *Adverbial Phrase* and many others, but I don't find them in my textbook. Instead, I find there the following:

> I (The subject) gave (the simple predicate) the letter (the direct
> object) to them (the prepositional indirect object).
>
> I (the subject) gave (the simple predicate) them (the indirect object)
> the letter (the direct object).
>
> A boy (the subject) feeds (the simple predicate) the dog (the direct
> object) with pleasure (the adverb of manner) in the yard (the adverb
> of place) every day (the adverb of time).

To my surprise, people here get confused when I use the term *the indirect prepositional object* referring to *to them*.

I've never seen anybody use the term *the simple predicate* or simply *predicate* referring to the verb of a sentence here. If someone used it, they meant the whole sentence, I guess, after the subject.

So, I've been wondering if anybody knows what's wrong with the terms which have been taught in Russia so far? Why, at least, some of them differ from the ones used by native speakers of English? And by which resources I can learn the proper ones?

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that native speakers of English rarely talk about grammar!  As such, unless you have an academic interest in linguistics, most speakers don't know lots of the technical jargon.  Most people know "noun, verb, adjective"  but not much more than that.

Comment: @JamesK Yeah, I understand that. I'm really keen to know all the nuts and bolts as well as theoretical stuff as far as the academic terms are concerned.

Comment: You probably are asking about something like *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* .... Fair warning: it's nearly 2000 pages long.

Comment: I'm not sure if this post is better suited for ELL Meta (resource request?). Anyway, we have a list of resources, including some grammar books which should include the terminology you seek: [Resources: Books](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/736/36187).